# web service: global.asax issuing errors

Tags: visual-studio-2013, global-asax

This is the line:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WebApiTest" Language="C#" %>
```

generates:

> Error  1   Illegal syntax. Expecting valid start name character.
>   Error   2   Character '%', hexadecimal value 0x25 is illegal in an XML name.
>   Error   3   The character '@', hexadecimal value 0x40 is illegal at the beginning of an XML name.
>   Error   4   Character '@', hexadecimal value 0x40 is illegal in an XML name.
>   Error   5   Missing attribute value on attribute 'Application'. 
>   Error   6   Character '%', hexadecimal value 0x25 is illegal in an XML name.

yet it runs ok but would like to get rid of these errors, not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct. Checkout the default editor of your file in VS, maybe you are mistakenly using a standard XML editor for editing the *.asax file.